# Во что записывать json в c#?

Tags: c#

Есть метод, он отправляет запрос на сервер и получает ответ в `json`. В какую переменную лучше записывать `json` для удобного распарса? И как записать метод для возврата этого `json`? Сейчас у меня это `public string` и возвращаю я его в строке.

Зелёный.

Comment: какие еще у вас есть варианты?

Comment: Я нашел сериализацию в объект через строку. Но не могу `using System.Text.Json;` , оно не хочет импортироваться.

Comment: Не во что? Обычно JSON в виде `string` не хранится, он получается и сразу десериализуется в классы, с которыми в последующим и работают. Если же надо обратно на сервер отдать JSON, то делают обратную сериализацию. Но чистый JSON не хранится, все зависит от задачи конечно.

Answer (score 1):

Если известна структура `json` (а это, я уверен на 99%, так), то создавайте такую же иерархию классов, как и структура `json`. После этого выполняете примерно следующее:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text.Json;

// .....
// Асинхронное получение ответа
var client = new HttpClient();
var responseMessage = await client.GetAsync(requestUrl);
if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var resultData = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ResponseDataStructure>(resultData);
}
```

где `ResponseDataStructure` - описанная вами получаемая структура данных.

P.S. пример на .net Core 3.0+. Вместо стандартного `JSON`-парсера от .NET можете использовать любой другой.

Answer (score 1):

Можете сериализацию и десериализацию сделать с помощью System.Runtime.Serialization.Json, которую нужно добавить в References. Например:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;

public class TestClass
{      
    public int ID { get; set; }      
    public string Name { get; set; }     
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

private string serialize(TestClass obj)
{
    var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(TestClass));
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        ser.WriteObject(stream, obj);
        stream.Position = 0;
        var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
        return sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
private TestClass deserialize(string json)
{
    var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(TestClass));
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
    {   
        return ser.ReadObject(stream) as TestClass;
    }
}
```